# Buddy classes and ViewModels in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

As far as I understand "Buddy Classes" is one way to add data annotations to an EF-created class. To add values for a dropdown, or to use a subset of properties in a View however - a ViewModel is adviceable. Is that correct? Or can I combine the two in one buddyviewmodelclass?

This is a bit confusing. It would be awesome to model up a class with data annotations and all in EF designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you got it right. A view model is a class that reflects all the specific properties of a given view. This view model could be composed of multiple model classes or be a subset of a single model class. This will depend on your model classes and the requirements of your views.

Comment: Ok, but then - with view model classes, I wont need the "buddy classes", right?

Comment: @joeriks, no you might not need them.

Comment: hmm... wouldn't Code First with an existing DB make this easier? seems like it by reading this post by Scott Guthrie http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx

Comment: @joeriks, the keyword here is **view models**. It is not models, not Entity Framework, not ORM, it is view models specifically tailored to the needs of a view. You can always take the Code First approach, etc, but this concerns your data access layer and models. In ASP.NET MVC it is a good practice to use view models and have a mapping between them and your domain models.

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm back to that practice now. The problem I saw was necessity to add much db-context-stuff to every viewmodel. But I dont need to I guess. I can simply query for the plain EF/db object and then automap it into the particular Viewmodel object. Is that the common approach?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov would you say that is is "OK" to use LINQ2SQL generated classes with "Buddy Classes" Validation directly as a model in a View? I do not mean like a simple class but a complex Table with many compelx FK relations? Can I justify using fully populated Model class in a View? To Edit data in a Form, submit that Complex Model back to a controller and use the Valid and Save directly in the controller? I am thinking overhead in hundreds of page views a minute and an azure role for example VS using a simple ViewModel that is transformed to Data in the Business logic.

Comment: @ppumkin, no, it's absolutely not ok to use your domain models in your views.